# Can I use a 'transformation' or something similar to calculate a result from two different DB's?

Tags: grafana

I'm using two different data sources in Grafana and need to use the result from each to calculate a percentage.  What I need is equivalent to A/B, where A is

`SELECT count(id) FROM Logs WHERE $__unixEpochFilter(RequestTimestamp DIV 1000)`

from Database 1 and B is

`SELECT count(id) FROM Entries WHERE $__unixEpochFilter(RequestTimestamp DIV 1000)`

from Database 2.  I can create a mixed data source panel and retrieve A and B, but can't find a way to perform an operation on the two results.

Comment: `SELECT a.a/b.b AS percentage FROM (SELECT count(id) AS a FROM Logs ...) AS a CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(id) AS b FROM Entries ...) AS b`

Answer (score 1):

You can move the subqueries to the `from` clause and use `cross join`:

```
SELECT l.cnt * 1.0 / e.cnt
FROM (SELECT count(id) as cnt
      FROM Logs
      WHERE $__unixEpochFilter(RequestTimestamp DIV 1000)
     ) l CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT count(id) as cnt
      FROM Entries
      WHERE $__unixEpochFilter(RequestTimestamp DIV 1000)
     ) e
```

The `* 1.0` is because DB2 does integer division.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I edited my question to make it more clear, but I don't think this will work since the Logs and Entries tables are in separate databases.

Comment: @fotherga . . . That doesn't make a difference.  You just need to reference the full path to the table in each subquery.